# How to DrawText in the right position?

Tags: c#, text, graphics, drawing

I want to draw a text using Graphic.DrawText method in a specific position. Suppose for example I need to draw my text giving the following bounds:

```
X = 10;
Y = 10;
Width = 100;
Height = 100;
```

I would expect that the left-most point of my string will be at 10, but this is the result if I add also a vertical line at `X = 10`:

```
g.DrawLine(Pen, new Point(10, 10), new Point(10, 100));
g.DrawString("Hello", Font, Color, new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100), Format);
```

[image]

As you can see my text seems *shifted*, it is not in correspondence of the line, which is at `X = 10`.

Why? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Nayan No, I'm using Windows Forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Is the `g` from same canvas object? Have you considered the spacing/alignments required for fonts? Fonts are not easy objects like line and circles.

Comment: g is the graphic object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The snippet is too shoddy to make the call.  Start with the "Format" argument, use new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypography) to reduce the spacing.